# Angular: Deregister a component but keep files and folders

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-module

I have a angular project which have few components that are not used currently but kept as I have plans to work on those in future. Removing the components from `declarations` from it's respective modules does not fully de-registers it. When I start the server again or create build the removed components throws errors that it cannot find the dependencies.

An example is below screenshot when I removed `compiler` component from `portal.module.ts` declaration it still throws error that it cannot find the `mat-icon`.

[image: deregister component]

Removing the whole folder solves the problem after removing the declaration but at this moment I want to keep the component folder. What I am expecting is that once I remove the component from declaration I will be able to run my project as normal by skipping those removed folders.

Is there any way around to solve this scenario?

Comment: If you have a version control and those files were previously in there, there is no harm in deleting those files. You can restore them from version control at any point. Other than that you can also just comment out all the code, effectively "emptying" the file.

Comment: please add some more information, it is not clear what exactly the problem is. i understand you removed a component from the module, but how exactly? did you remove the import statement AND the entry in `declarations`?

did you run `ng build` again, or is this just the hot-reload functionality?

are you running this inside an IDE? it may be that some caching functionality causes this problem.

Comment: @SimonB yes you are correct. I just removed the import statement & also from declaration and then tried to build/start the dev server

Answer (score 0):

To use `<mat-icon>` in a component, the `MatIconModule` needs to be imported into that component's `imports` tree (i.e. whichever `NgModule` is declaring the component). If you have uncommented references to `<mat-icon>` in a component, and the `MatIconModule` is not found, you will correctly receive that error.

Options:

- Comment references to `<mat-icon>` in any HTML templates in which the component is not receiving an imported instance of `MatIconModule`
- Ensure that the `MatIconModule` is imported in the components declaring `NgModule`
- As @mike-s suggested (and likely the best option for code quality), delete the unused code and store it on a separate branch/use git to retrieve it again when needed